# nginx SSI: Is it possible to dynamically set <base href=<!--#echo var="URL" -->?

Tags: nginx

I need to set the `<base href="/">` value within a static files SPA dynamically and depending on a particular HTTP header.

I was thinking of using SSI (Server Side Includes) for this:

`<base href=<!--#echo var="URL" -->`

and setting the URL in the `nginx.conf` to the HTTP header (does that even work?)

As I do not have a working nginx with the SSI module compiled, I was wondering what you think: Does this work? Or is SSI only for including additional HTML files?